# Python 3 - Scrape Inner Div's Info with BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** some website with beautifulsoup but i couldn't make it work. On the site there is main div i'm taking that div with this code :

```
for divs in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'row div-1'}): #I'm taking main div

     innerDivs = divs.find_all('div') #Taking inner div's in main div

     for inner in innerDivs: #loop for all inner divs

          print(inner) # I can print every inner div so it's working
```

Here one inner div structure :

```
<div class="inner-div preset multi">
<img class="img-resp high" data- 
src="https://image.test.co/skin/54asd15q1we12as1d1q/png.png" 
title="New Skin" width="100%"/>
</div>
```

I want to acces "title" and image-src but i don't know how. I tried 'inner.title' etc but i failed. Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to find all `<img>` tags, and then just get their attributes, in your case it's `['title']` attribute.

In your example, you has only the one image tag, so you able to get him via list index `[0]`, and then get his attributes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


template = """
<div class="inner-div preset multi">
<img class="img-resp high" data- 
src="https://image.test.co/skin/54asd15q1we12as1d1q/png.png" 
title="New Skin" width="100%"/>
</div>
"""

source = BeautifulSoup(template, 'html.parser')

images = source.find_all('img')
print(images[0]['title']) # New skin
print(images[0]['src']) # https://image.test.co/skin/54asd15q1we12as1d1q/png.png
print(images[0]['width']) # 100%
```

Comment: Thank you soo much!